# Issue Mounting SharePoint 2010 content database in 2013

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-database

I'm in the middle of an upgrade from 2010 to 2013, and I'm running into an issue when attempting to upgrade one of my content databases using PowerShell. The content databases attached to my other web applications have mounted fine, but this particular one is presenting issues.

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

> Mount-SPContentDatabase : The DELETE permission was denied on the
>   object 'TVF_Features_PK', database 'MyContentDB', schema 'dbo'.

I've given the account that I'm using to execute to PS command db_owner permissions on the database, but that doesn't seem to be helping. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this to go through by giving the account I was using to mount the database full sysadmin permissions on the database server.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the account in question also has Securityadmin (& Dbcreator) fixed server roles on the SQL Server instance.

For more details, see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However those permissions were already applied.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, @EvanM.